# Gathering JSON data from external file

Tags: jquery, html, json

I Have a JSON file named destinations.json and i would like to get the data from this file to display in a dropdown box on HTML. The JSON file is as shown below

```
{
    "Destinations": [
    {
        "destinationName": "London",
        "destinationID": "lon"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "New York",
        "destinationID": "nyc"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "Paris",
        "destinationID": "par"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "Rome",
        "destinationID": "rom"
    }
    ]
}
```

So far, i have made sure the jquery library is available and then created a function which will fetch data from the JSON file when clicked, shown below.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#fetch').click(function() {
    $.post('http://jonathangatenby.co.uk/Candidate/json/destinations.json', {}, function(data) {
        $.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
            $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' + v.destinationName + '</option>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

from here, i have simple HTML which will give me a drop down box.

```
<select id="destinations">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="fetch">Fetch JSON</a>
```

This doesn't seem to work, and all the files are on the same server.

Comment: open the console and check for errors, specifically "not allowed - cross origin" errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jquery code :

```
$(function() {
    $('#fetch').click(function(){
        $.getJSON('yourjsonfile.json', function(data) {
            destinations = data['Destinations']

            $.each(destinations, function(id, destination) {
                $('select').append('<option value="">'+destination["destinationName"]+'</option>')
            })
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you send the link of your json file ? I will make a fiddle to show you that my code is working.

Comment: You're right. The code is not working because you have to do a relative link to your json file : like `folder/file.json` and not `http://mysite.com/file.json`. Try with relative url i think.